# Creating a Magento Extension - Instructions Followed, No Package in var/connect

Tags: magento

I am repackaging a new version of a Magento Extension and am running into some trouble.

I am following the instructions found on the Magento Connect site:  http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/packagingmagentoconnectextensions6%200.pdf

The problem comes in the "Save Data and Create the Package" step.  I finish entering all the information in the various steps of the extension creator, include all of the files and directories for the extension, I click "Save Data and Create the Package" and nothing happens.  Certainly no "The package data has been saved" as it appears is what should happen by other posts that I have read.

I double checked the write permission of the magento/var/connect folder and all appear well.

Are there any settings within Magento that may be off?  Is it a permissions issue that I need to dig into further?  Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem what I did and it actually worked was this command: chmod -R 777 var/ in magento root directory. If you will take a look at the end of the PDF that you provided there is a note in Section F: Load Local Package saying: First you should set write permissions to the appropriate folders.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I did verify the permissions before I posted and both the var and var/connect folders are all the correct permissions.  I just updated them again, just in case.  Still having the same result.